# CSS files doesn't work as expected on a Jekyll site

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to create a Jekyll based website hosted on GitHub. I'm beginner in RoR and Jekyll. Seems like there's some CSS problem with the implemented site: on the original theme the magnifier glass should be over the post images. On my implementation the magnifier glass separates and appears above the top-left corner of the post thumbnails. Also, the modal dialog which opens up when you click the post is different: it's not full screen, and the cross on the top-right is not there either.

Original theme:

- Demo: https://jeromelachaud.github.io/freelancer-theme/
- Source: https://github.com/jeromelachaud/freelancer-theme/

My implementation:

- Demo: https://mrcsabatoth.github.io/
- Source: https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.github.io/

As I was instructed on the theme's repo, I started with the theme's main branch. That has all the config yaml settings and proper variable resolution (except site base address).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo is missing this CSS code

```
#programs  .caption:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#programs  .caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(24,188,156,.9);
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
#programs * {
  z-index: 2;
}
#programs  .program-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}
#programs .program-link .caption .caption-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

this code is exists in the original demo which is responsible for showing the caption on hover

but the different is you are using `#programs`  while in the original css using `#portfolio`

Comment: Thanks, good catch! I thought there's a problem with the theme itself.